# problem in table column name without underscore

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data

I have got a table named contract with a column in Entity table named contractexternalid.
The column is created correctly as contract_external_id but when I performe a repository.save  it tries to set column as contractexternalid and throw me an error.
It is the first time I got this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the column name explicitly:

```
@Column(name = "contract_external_id")
String contractExternalId;
```

Comment: I thougth of this also. But I have got many tables with many columns...